# Checking that the value of an object member matches a Typescript generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I need to construct an object based off the potential values from a type. How would I go about narrowing that object down?

```ts
type Values = {
    foo: boolean,
    bar: string
}

type Properties<Type> = {
    name: keyof Type;
    // I want to narrow values so that it only accepts the matching value from Type
    values: Type[keyof Type][];
};

const properties: Properties<Values>[] = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        // Should complain because 'false' !== boolean
        values: [true, 'false'],
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        // Should be ok
        values: ['hello', 'goodbye'],
    }
];
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM5QLxQN4CgpQBmA9sQFxQBGpCEcAdgDT5VwBOFqwbAlvQOa4AvrlyhIUAAptikNsB5oAPABVwEAHyYcLenAC2ECgGsIIYoShrIAbhYB6e1ACSUAO4NgUYMSh62Mm5QAG6IKOiovsAAFnBePPHoxPQIIFBwAMYZEGDA6DHQ+nEZ0Xz8IWHQhDL6VuosochoFNYQANqm5patALptPXZCdrgZyVxQYDJyCs1SUxDyiqhK8E2oGv3abSx4BAR6hhQA5CTER8x7UI5QAMrRxEgIACZQo-pgCHB8VBAZcEioaAnRCAo5QACEGCw1GItAYLAIjXCFDa3BQjCgwIQoJ6FygQjxuz2ByMmMo7HOCKuTjuD2ePygxGMVKRszaR2iEAQCDOGKO-FIT0oIAgR1xLBEA1wQA)

Comment: Are you tied to `Properties<Type>` having the structure `{ name: string, values: something[] }`?

Comment: @Caleth I am unfortunately. I'm trying to type an existing system, without having to rewrite lots of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use mapped types for this.

The issue is currently a union is created based on the possible value. If instead you map over the keys and create the output type as you want you end up with an object type with all possible types.

Then if you index the mapped type with `keyof Type` you can get the correctly mapped values.

A type like this can work

```
type Properties<Type> = {
    [K in keyof Type]: { name: K; values: Type[K][] };
}[keyof Type];
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM5QLxQN4CgoFQBmA9iQFxQBGZCEcAdgNz6FVwBOlqwHAlgwDmLAL4tcoSFAAKHEpA7A+aADwAVcBAB8mHKwIBtANJQBUANYQQJIlA2QAupWxQGcALYRKRplABuiCiolPYQxg4GDlBiuCIGlta2oQ7iktBqurLyEIrKqCrwyGha4gDGJAw8UGByCkpolFl1eQWBxZG6Bvp6hL2uHl5QAESkJEMANN29APTTUADKABYkSAgAJlDl7mAIcGZUEKVwSKjQAOREiKdnUACEGFg0JHSMU4QBRcFQBrwo48OXBCnIYOSa9ERgwh4PqENyeShDdgcCZvAizBbLVYbA5QEjmVH+NpfAxDRYQBAIMb-IaCMhrKggCAgyEECG4FK4IA)

More detail
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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)

Comment: Formatting is opinionated, but surely no one wants to look at code with 0 whitespace between characters whatsoever, so I've gone ahead and formatted the code.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! So in this instance, before indexing we build up something a bit like:
`foo: { name: foo, values: boolean[] }, bar: { name: foo, values: boolean[] }`?

How does indexing it work? I'm struggling to get my head around that bit.

Comment: yea nice one, exactly that type gets created, its basically just explaining all possible options by key. But we don't need the keys, so if you access an object by saying keyof its basically giving you just the values.

You could have a type ValueOf<T>=T[keyof T]

Assume we had the above type T. if you do T['foo'] just get the foo part, so you do T['foo'|'bar'] you get union of foo part and bar part, and generalized it becomes keyof T and gives T[keyof T] = all values union

Comment: So does it:
A) interate over the union?, or B) create a union and then TS pattern-matches based on the supplied name?

Comment: Actually I guess it's the latter, as [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawJYDsDmBBKBeKAbwCgoyp0BDAWwgC4oByAMwHtXGAaKAN0oBsArhADODAEbt+ESugDaAXWIBfYsVCRYCFBkwAhfEVLkqtBo3GUATl14DhYqCOBXdilWo3R4SNFhiGPjpYuAA+Wr66emqIrOjOUGBWrJBWwKiiDEF+mDCKhnLGZCTkpRQ09FAARGysVZxFZQD0TVAAynCsgvwAJlCx1GD8lBhQ4kiUgiLQLALTjFAAhHgEkqzSso2lfEKZUHIuwtw1cxBVCg2lypfkJWVkppVVllb1W+Qt7Z3dfeNQrMh3mQdg4GHIqgh+Pw6sdMOweuIQGcLo1rsQFABuYhAA) seems to illustrate

Comment: Yea that's it, cause no such thing as iterating union I think. Its 2 steps. First create the mapped type. Then access it with keyof, I think the subtle part to understand is the keyof creates a union. In this example keyof Values is "foo"|"bar". I'll add a link to typescript playground with some detail should be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class that is only instantiated by a code path that verifies the type

```
class Property<Type> {
  private name_: keyof Type;
  private values_: Type[keyof Type][]
  private constructor(name: keyof Type, values: Type[keyof Type][])
  {
    this.name_ = name;
    this.values_ = values;
  }
  get name(): keyof Type { return this.name_; }
  get values(): Type[keyof Type][] { return this.values_; }
  static make<Type, K extends keyof Type>(name: K, values: Type[K][]): Property<Type>{
    return new Property<Type>(name, values);
  }
};
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM5QLxQN4CgpQBmA9sQFxQBGpCEcAdgDT5VwBOFqwbAlvQOa4AvrlwBjBHFToACm2KQ2oADwAVcBAB8OFmF4A3OMGj04AWwgB9CgGsIIYoSjrIAbl0Gj0Q8jTXnGgDadg5OLhAAuoERHjyGxlBixPRcbEhiwMRsABSmFrb2jgGQjFA%20KKgU4cGFYRpREQCULHgEBMAAFjyoAHR5VphQ-e5tUJ3dPeV%20g1OoI1AiBPwQwEPmENmNBaHF0NhQbCtIbPRjXb39lq4LLMurs5tVQSFF4Q04B0cnZxOzVzcELhGHhiKBmOB2NQaUoAaSgEAAHsZ6AATdAvOqQTS5dYUGGlWZPSCBGENLZQOQKCBKEBQrGtNqHYDHU70CAAdwp8kUKnC2P6BMQFUa8xEQnc4mSXCgeipSh4aAolJ5tPgvlQmmig0CLGV1NAPXBdmyAHISMQTaVAtwUKUzYhUBATU1mAQ9TTDRCNibKOxLVBAiaOhAEAgLXb%20KQUZQQE6mrgIu4gA)